# Camera in virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, webcam

Cannot use Camera in ubuntu/virtual box, running cheese displays black screen with "No Device Found" text.
I know that this question has been answered in different forums but none of the solutions appear to be working on my machine.
I'm running Win10 Host on Lenovo Yoga 370, with Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS in Oracle Virtual Box 6.0.

I'm loading the camera through Devices/Webcams/Usb Video Device and here are the outputs:

```
cheese:
  cheese-application.vala:211: Error during camera setup: No device found
```

```
lsusb:
  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  Bus 002 Device 003: ID 80ee:0030 VirtualBox 
  Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
  Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

```
dmesg:
  [   39.386510] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci-pci
  [   39.738147] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=80ee, idProduct=0030, bcdDevice= 1.00
  [   39.738155] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
  [   39.738161] usb 2-2: Product: VirtualBox Webcam - USB Video Device
  [   39.738165] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: VirtualBox
  [   39.738169] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: e6e88a150d76b078
  [   39.788121] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
  [   39.798989] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
  [   39.817235] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device VirtualBox Webcam - USB Video Device (80ee:0030)
  [   39.851022] uvcvideo 2-2:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized! 
  [   39.851024] uvcvideo 2-2:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
  [   39.851586] input: VirtualBox Webcam - USB Video D as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/input/input8
  [   39.852123] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
  [   39.852125] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
```

any pointers would be helpful

Comment: What is the actual problem you're encountering?

Comment: I'm trying to use camera in ubuntu client, but it does not appear to be recognized. _updated the question_

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is an issue with cheese, other video apps (Guvcview, skype) show the stream without any issue in the virtual box environment.